# There was an error parsing the query.when retrieving data from a .sdf-file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am writing a program in C# using Visual Studio 2008 and gets an error when retrieving data from a `.sdf` file

> There was an error parsing the query in `SqlCeConnection`

My code is

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCeDataAdapter da;

try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    if(mode == "update")
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT eq_id, description, bl_id, fl_id,  rm_id, modelno, category, eq_std, comments FROM eq where (isModified = 1) SELECT * FROM eq_log";
    else if(mode == "create")
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT eq_id, description, bl_id, fl_id, rm_id, modelno, category, eq_std, comments FROM eq where (isModified = 2) SELECT * FROM eq_log";

    da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
catch (Exception db)
{
}
```

The error is:

> There was an error parsing the query.[ Token     line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = SELECT ]
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query.There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = SELECT

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 select statement in cmd.CommandText. You need to separate them by **`;`**.

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCeDataAdapter da;

try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    if(mode == "update")
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT eq_id, description, bl_id, fl_id,  rm_id, modelno, category, eq_std, comments FROM eq where (isModified = 1); SELECT * FROM eq_log";
    else if(mode == "create")
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT eq_id, description, bl_id, fl_id, rm_id, modelno, category, eq_std, comments FROM eq where (isModified = 2); SELECT * FROM eq_log";

    da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
catch (Exception db)
{
}
```

Tell me if this is working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single SELECT per command with SQL Server Compact, so you must return two DataSets/DataTables